# Click Event in a cell of a Flex Spark Datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I have the following code:

```
<s:DataGrid id="preciosGrid" top="65" width="935" height="379" horizontalCenter="0" requestedRowCount="4"
            dataProvider="{clientModel.model.arrayColumnProducts}">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn                           headerText="edit" width="30" itemRenderer="renderers.EditGridRender"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="product"       headerText="Product" width="200" editable="false"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="provider"  headerText="" width="52" editable="true" itemRenderer="renderers.PriceCellItemRenderer"></s:GridColumn>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

and need to be able to catch only the double-click event from the Edit cell (First column).

My itemRenderer is:

```
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" clipAndEnableScrolling="true"
                width="50" height="30">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import events.EditItemEvent;

        import mx.controls.Alert;
        override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {}
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Image id="btn_edit" horizontalCenter="0" source="@Embed('assets/images/edit_icon.png')"
         verticalCenter="0"
         doubleClickEnabled="true"
         doubleClick="Alert.show('clicked')"/>
```

How can I pass the click event to the main App from the ItemRenderer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be creating a EventListener inside you ItemRenderer, which dispatches a custom event where bubbling is set to true. And in you main application you can listen for that custom event.

Comment: And how can I guess which item triggered the event? I mean, the row in the datagrid.

Comment: Therefore each event-object has 2 properties. currentTarget is the one that binds the listener, target is the one that dispatched the event.